# Firebase database remove() "is not a function"

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

This code works:

```
firebase.database().ref($scope.language).orderByChild('word').equalTo($scope.word).once('value')
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  })
```

It logs the object and its key.

This code doesn't work:

```
firebase.database().ref($scope.language).orderByChild('word').equalTo($scope.word).remove()
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log("Removed!");
  })
```

The error message is:

```
TypeError: firebase.database(...).ref(...).orderByChild(...).equalTo(...).remove is not a function
```

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#remove) makes `remove()` look simple. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only load data once you know its specific location in the JSON tree. To determine that location, you need to execute the query and loop through the matching results:

```
firebase.database().ref($scope.language).orderByChild('word').equalTo($scope.word).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    child.ref.remove();
    console.log("Removed!");
  })
});
```

If you only want to log after all have been removed, you can use `Promise.all()`:

```
firebase.database().ref($scope.language).orderByChild('word').equalTo($scope.word).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  var promises = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    promises.push(child.ref.remove());
  })
  Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
    console.log("All removed!");
  })
});
```

Comment: The first one doesn't quite work, it needs another closure. The code looks awful in this comment so I'll post an answer. The second code block works perfectly. Thanks for the fast response! This should be in the documentation.

Comment: That first one was a typo, thanks for catching. It was simply meant to log after deleting *each* matching node. The second one logs after removing *all* matching nodes.

Comment: Frank, I have an idea for an April Fools video you could make, about the new Firebase personal database product for storing all your digital stuff, called Fire.Me. :-)  Make a presentation to the boss with random PowerPoint slides and tech industry buzzwords, and "Fire me!" said repeatedly with the enthusiasm of a marketing person. No promises that you'll keep your job. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is Frank's first code block with another closure. Without the closure the record is removed from the database but then there's an error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: snapshot.forEach(...).then is not a function
```

Adding a closure fixes the error message.

```
firebase.database().ref($scope.language).orderByChild('word').equalTo($scope.word).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        child.ref.remove();
      }); // a closure is needed here
    }).then(function() {
      console.log("Removed!");
    });
```